Programming a 2013 dodge avenger key
I replace my ignition switch with another one from the same year make and model as my old one. I got it from a salvage yard cause it came with a actual key. It's a 2013 dodge avenger. How can I program this key to the vehicle so it will run and get my car back on the road without having to pay a dealership a bunch of money to do it. It was my mother's car who passed away and I inherited it. It's in excellent condition cause she took really good care of it.

Page 17 of your owner's manual gives the procedure for the owner to program a new key without involving the dealer.
Unfortunately, it requires you to already have two working keys that can turn the ignition switch. This allows you to program a third key (or more).
This probably means that you're going to need a dealer to program the new key.
